# Asp:GridView.DataBind() using AJAX WebService Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5

Hai,

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Framework 3.5. I wrote a WebService and I added that WebService in my page through ScriptManager Service Path. I wrote a method in the webservice, that returns List<...>. I captured that value from JavaScript function. Now I want to bind that List<...> value to with my Asp:GridView using JavaScript. Help me .....

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because of viewstate. It's not accessible in static context.

Try asp:updatePanel (it can persist viewstate between callbacks) or code stateless grid by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't bind datagrid using JavaScript. As Arnis mentioned you can  use UpdatePanel. Alternatively you can use Jquery to create a table structure which look and feel like a grid. However with this approach you it would be tricky to do paging.